# Rank/Label a binary time series variable in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series

I have a simple time series where a switch is turned on and off by an operator. My aim is to label each of the "turned on" phases with a different ID, e.g., the result with column eventID would look like this:

```
val eventDF = sc.parallelize(List(("2016-05-01 10:00:00", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:00:30", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:01:00", 1, 1),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:01:20", 1, 1),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:02:10", 1, 1),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:03:30", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:04:00", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:05:20", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:06:10", 1, 2),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:06:30", 1, 2),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:07:00", 1, 2),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:07:20", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:08:10", 0, 0),
                                  ("2016-05-01 10:08:50", 0, 0)))
                .toDF("timestamp", "switch", "eventID")
```

So far, I tried the rank/rangeBetween/lag window functions without any luck...therefore, any hint is appreciated.

Comment: It is possible and not particularly hard, but won't scale unless you have another layer of grouping.

Comment: Yes, you are right- this is the first step to separate/group the events. How would you do it?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/42448564/6910411 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43806269/6910411 - it is essentially the same problem.